# HttpHandler and XML files

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httphandler

I would like to intercept any request made to the server for XML files. I thought that it might be possible with an HttpHandler. It's coded and it works... on localhost only (?!?!).

So, why is it working on localhost only? Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.xml" type="FooBar.XmlHandler, FooBar" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is my C# :

```
namespace FooBar
{
    public class XmlHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
            Response.Write(xmlString);
        }
    }
}
```

As you might have seen, I'm writing the xmlString directly in the response, it's only temporary because I'm still wondering how I could give the filename instead (that's the second question ;) )

What is supposed to be written in the response is only the xml filename that will be retrieved by a flash app.

Thanks

Details : 
Using IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003.

**Edit :**
When calling the page from another computer it looks like it's not getting to the HttpHandler. However, the mapping for IIS have been done correctly.

Comment: Your code looks fine. When you say it is not working when not on localhost, exactly what does that mean? What do you see (or not see) that tells you it is not working? How are you calling this? Have you used Fiddler and/or the VS debugger to watch the request?

Comment: @Ray : Added details. Does it matter if the assembly is a ASP.Net website?

Comment: It should work as you have set it up. Stefano's point is a good place to check - if IIS is handling the request and not passing it on to asp.net, this is what you will see. Do you see the request in the IIS log?

Comment: @Ray : I can see the request in the IIS log file. But I get a 402.1 (SecurityError), 401.1(Not authorized) and finally a 404.2 (File not found). It's kind of weird since if I remove it from IIS Manager I can access the file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an IIS6 server at hand at the moment, but there are two steps required:

- map the xml extension to ASP.NET (use the executable path from aspx extension): [Setting Application Mappings in IIS 6.0](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4c840252-fab7-427e-a197-7facb6649106.mspx?mfr=true)
- tell ASP.NET to use your custom handler: [Deploying HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/784eeb32-d781-4917-95b3-34f302a81680.mspx?mfr=true)

The first step is not obvious because the Visual Studio integrated web server is mapping all requests to ASP.NET.

Other resources:

- [How to: Create Synchronous HTTP Handlers](http://www.yaldex.com/asp_net_tutorial/html/daa90a3b-47d7-45f7-98cc-188fa56424c9.htm)

Comment: Ah. It's good to know that VS automatically maps all requests to the asp.net. Thanks for the summary. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

if IIS is version 6.0 or previous,
handler will be ignored, because IIS handle xml extensions without calling ASP.NET process.
you can change it from IIS Manager,saying iis to use asp.net for handling XML.

Comment: Yes. The IIS Manager is already configured to handle xml extension with my dll. But still doesn't work.

Comment: IIS should be configured to have asp.net handle xml files, not your dll. COnfigure xml files the same way you see aspx files configured.

Comment: How can I define a custom behavior if it's asp.net that handles the xml?

Comment: When asp.net handles the request, it will use the mapping you set up in web.config to send the request to your httphandler